# When creating postgres container, environment POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS is ignored in Kubernetes

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm trying to set **lc-collate** parameter for postgres container, using env POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS. But this env is ignored and after deployment applying I get default value of **lc_collate**

here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-postgres-1
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
      tier: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
        tier: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: postgres
          name: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: --lc-collate=C
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: user
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          volumeMounts:
            - name: example-postgres
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          args: ["-c", "max_connections=200"]
      volumes:
        - name: example-postgres
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: example-postgres
```

At the same time I'm trying to set **POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--lc-collate=C"** by using docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgresTest"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "user"
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--lc-collate=C"
    ports:
      - "3432:5432"
```

and it works for me

What am i doing wrong in kuberntes deployment by setting **POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS** ? If it is wrong, how to set **lc_collate** by creating container creting?

I'm trying to set **lc-collate** parameter for postgres container, using env POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS. But this env is ignored and after applying I get default value of **lc_collate**

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks OK. I've applied your manifest on 1 of my GKE clusters and it seems to working fine.

However, In your docker compose, your postgres version is `13.3` whereas in k8s manifest, its `latest` (version when not mentioned means latest). Try setting 13.3 in manifest too and check if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work anyway. After deployment applying I see lc_collate = en_US.utf8, but i want to see lc_collate = C, because i set it in deployment. Wnen I do it by docker-compose, everything is ok and i see lc_collate = C.

Comment: also i tried to apply everything with postgres:latest - i've got the same problem. Docker-compose script works fine, but by applying kubernetes deployment script lc_collate is ignored

Comment: I have already tried everything - I set lc_collate with undescore and lc-collate with dash